# SlackのスラッシュコマンドでGAS(google apps script)を実行したい

Tags: google-apps-script, api, slack

Slack APIのスラッシュコマンドでGASの起動をリクエストしたく、GASを「ウェブアプリケーションとして導入」で下記の設定を行いました。

・次のユーザーとしてアプリケーションを実行:⇒自分
・アプリケーションにアクセスできるユーザー:⇒組織の全員

＃セキュリティ上の問題により、GoogleDriveの公開は組織内としており、アクセス範囲として「(社外含む）全員」は選択できない状況となっています。

アクセス範囲が「(社外含む）全員」であればスラッシュコマンドからGASのリクエストが成功することは分かっているのですが、現在の公開範囲で動作する方法があれば教えていただきたいです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 主題としては「組織の全員がアクセスできる、ウェブアプリケーションとしてデプロイしたGASをSlackから実行できるかどうか、できるならどのようにするか」という感じでしょうか？

Comment: @PicoSushi さん
コメントありがとうございます。ご認識いただいた通りです。
ググっても、GASの公開範囲を組織外からのアクセスも許可する「全員(匿名ユーザーを含む)」にするものしか見つからず、困っている状況です。